# Typescript json parse error

Tags: angular, typescript

The actual response json string is huge, i am providing here the sample which looks similar, this is the hardcoded json string endpoint response

```
        "{ 
         \"country\": {
            \"state\": {
              \"province\": {
                \"public\": {
                  \"Id\": \"121212\",
                  \"Name\" : \"xyz\"
                },
                \"private\": {
                  \"Id\": \"2323232\",
                  \"Name\": \"abc\"
                }
              }
            }
          }
         }"
```

And the typescript :

```
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(
        (res:any) => res.json()
      )
      .catch((error:any) => { console.log(error); return error;});
  }
```

the above script is not helping me, not able to parse and get the values
Eg: - res.json().country is 'undefined'

May be i can put this way, how to handle the json string responses in typescript ?

Comment: thats not a valid JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The error actually is i am not able to parse and get values from json, they all are 'undefined' Eg:- res.json().country is 'undefined' . what is the way we can handle the json strings in typescript ?

Comment: Error messages and details should be in the Question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, the problem was with my Json having quotes (")

this response json worked fine.

```
{ 
         \"country\": {
            \"state\": {
              \"province\": {
                \"public\": {
                  \"Id\": \"121212\",
                  \"Name\" : \"xyz\"
                },
                \"private\": {
                  \"Id\": \"2323232\",
                  \"Name\": \"abc\"
                }
              }
            }
          }
         }
```